# Disabling ItemLanguageFallback not working

Tags: language-fallback

I want to use only FieldLanguageFallback and NOT ItemLanguageFallback.

I have a multisite configuration running with

```
enableFieldLanguageFallback=true
```

and with

```
enableItemLanguageFallback=false
```

on my site configs, I've set these settings and

```
enforceVersionPresence="true"
```

now I've created my site in German and I've taken a look into my English site where only some content is present in English and here the whole content is shown (mostly in German) also from content items that have NO Version in the English Language.

I thought, that Content would not show up when I have no version from a specific content item in this language and the item-level fallback would only be active when I have an Item version in this language?

So I have a lot content items like this:

[image]

but the related content is shown on the page in german.

The Settings for Language Fallback I've made on my site are right so far I can see but strange ist the following:

As you can see I've Version 1 but Versions Count = 0 how can this be?

[image]

Where can I see where the Version is resolved I get back here?

Comment: Q.E.D on why these 3 features in combination should be avoided like the plague ;-)

Answer (score 4):

First of all. Items don't have versions, only field values do.

So enabling field level fallback does exactly what you would expect. Item level fallback is a virtual construct.

Secondly, what you're doing breaks with Sitecore's recommendation that state:

> You should not use both item- and field-level fallback on the same item because it makes it difficult to maintain an overview of the versions that different items and fields fall back to.

Which is more or less *exactly* describing your current situation.

That said; the answer to your question - if you enable field level fallback, you will get fallback values for your field values; regardless of the item level fallback setting.

Source: [Enable and set up language fallback](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/enable-and-set-up-language-fallback.html)

Comment: sorry but I am not shure If I missunderstood something in english but they wrote **You should NOT use both item- and field-level fallback on the same item** that means that only one of the Flags should be active or? Like I descriped above, I have only item or field level activated.

Comment: But what you're saying is; that on your item - if you HAVE a German "version" and you DO NOT have an English "version" - German content is being shown on the English "version". Which is exactly what fallback is supposed to do.

Comment: I've updates my question with an other screenshot, where you can see that I got back 1 Version but I've no Versions